# Change metrics.properties in bitnami spark helm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, bitnami

I use bitnami spark helm to deploy spark on k8s. I want to change metrics.properties, I made config map and mount that to `/opt/bitnami/spark/conf`. I got this error:

> mv: cannot move '/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/metrics.properties.template'
> to '/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/metrics.properties': Device or resource
> busy

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create image from bitnami spark Dockerfile and  use my customized merics.properties and copy that in image with merics.properties.template.

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it possible to mount custom config via configmap. See https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/spark/values.yaml